# Elegant way to auto-adjust column width

Tags: tables, tabularx, textwidth, column-width

I am asking myself if there is not a more convenient, elegant way to automatically adjust every column in a table to fit into the page and to have perfect enough way for the containing text without receiving over- or underfull hboxes. Right now I only use the `tabularx` package or adjust the column width with `p{0.XXX\textwidth}`.

Comment: In the environments of both `nicematrix` and `tabularray`, we have weights for the `X` columns (eg you can put in the preamble of your array `X[1]X[2]X[3]`).

Comment: also tabulary which determines the column widths based on the content, but it depends which boxes you mean. the overall size of the table (which if too large will make an over full box on the page) or linebreaking within the narrow columns, which can form overfull boxes if no break found or underful if spaces have to be stretched, ther eit often helps to set text `\raggedright`

Comment: Thank you, `\raggedright` works perfectly! I just used it the wrong way till now...

Comment: I want to add another question concerning this topic to have an example where `\raggedright` is useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619963/182263.