# Why do I receive underful hbox warning with this MWE?

Tags: tables, tabularx, boxes

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Scores of the individual metrics}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{p{0.118\textwidth} p{0.1312\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.119\textwidth} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
        Metric & Name & Raw score & Normalized score & Min value & Max value & Goal \\
        Logistic Detection  & Logistic Regression Detection & 0.0298 & 0.0298 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        SVC Detection & SVC Detection & 0.0217 & 0.0217 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        GM Log Likelihood & Gaussian Mixture Log Likelihood & -177.0716 & 0.0000 & -inf & inf & MAXIMIZE \\
        CS Test & Chi-Squared & 0.3141 & 0.3141 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        KS Test & Inverted Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic &  0.6796 & 0.6796 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        KS Test Extended & Inverted Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic & 0.6971 & 0.6971 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        Continuous KL Divergence & Continuous Kullback–Leibler Divergence & 0.4036 & 0.4036 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        Discrete KL Divergence & Discrete Kullback–Leibler Divergence & 0.1507 & 0.1507 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I try around since hours to get this table looking fine without any warnings but I can't figure out how...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is warning you about the over-stretched spaces trying to justify the text in the first column

[image]

set this raggedright like the later columns:

I shortened the headings a bit and get no warnings from

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Scores of the individual metrics}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
@{}
>{\raggedright}p{0.14\textwidth}
 >{\raggedright}X
>{\raggedright}p{0.1\textwidth}
>{\raggedright}p{0.119\textwidth}
l
l
l
@{}}
        Metric & Name & Raw score & Norm.\ score & Min& Max & Goal \\
        Logistic Detection  & Logistic Regression Detection & 0.0298 & 0.0298 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        SVC Detection & SVC Detection & 0.0217 & 0.0217 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        GM Log Likelihood & Gaussian Mixture Log Likelihood & -177.0716 & 0.0000 & -inf & inf & MAXIMIZE \\
        CS Test & Chi-Squared & 0.3141 & 0.3141 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\
        KS Test & Inverted Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic &  0.6796 & 0.6796 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        KS Test Extended & Inverted Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic & 0.6971 & 0.6971 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        Continuous KL Divergence & Continuous Kullback–Leibler Divergence & 0.4036 & 0.4036 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE \\  
        Discrete KL Divergence & Discrete Kullback–Leibler Divergence & 0.1507 & 0.1507 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & MAXIMIZE  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```